# How should I cite an arXiv paper the proper way in my bibliography (with references to pages in that paper)?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, arxiv

I can't find any information on the internet on how to do that properly.

What I do is this for example:

```
\bibitem{1} O. M. Shalit. \emph{Dilation theory: a guided tour} (2020), 11-13. arXiv:2002.05596v2.
```

But I don't know if this is the right and "official" way of citing arXiv articles in my Master Thesis.

How should I do this properly?

Comment: If you are doing a thesis, it might be worth using `biblatex` or `natbib` etc rather then manual but to each their own :)

Comment: @JamesT What I mean is: Is the order I've used here in this reference alright? I'm confused about the year-pages-arXiv order here.

Comment: I have a feeling that is off-topic here then, I would answer in this comment if I knew the answer but this site is for TeX and co., correct bib formatting for specific journals/repositories is probably best asked on a science/maths site

Comment: This is going to depend upon the requirements of your university. Check with their pub office (but the order you're suggesting seems to be the norm).